# Log4j smtp appender to send just one email for all errors

Tags: java, log4j, smtpappender

I have a program that processes ids. Some ids get multiple errors on the ETL.
I am setting up log4j smtp to send an email when I encounter an error or fatal.
Right now it will send 5 emails for five errors for one program run. I would like to aggregate them into one email. I have log4j properties set instead of xml.

properties. I hid to and from

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG,stdout,fileout, sendMail

log4j.appender.sendMail=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.sendMail.Threshold=Error
log4j.appender.sendMail.SMTPHost=mailhost
log4j.appender.sendMail.From=hidden
log4j.appender.sendMail.To=hidden
log4j.appender.sendMail.Subject=Failure
log4j.appender.sendMail.BufferSize=1
#log4j.appender.sendMail.evaluatorClass=TriggerLogEvent
log4j.appender.sendMail.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.sendMail.layout.ConversionPattern=%m
```

Theres just not much info out on log4j smtp appender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about creating another class to aggregate the error messages and create a new logger for that class

so first you create a class that will hold all of the error messages for a particular id

```
public class TestLog4j {

static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestLog4j.class.getName());

int id;
ArrayList<String> errors,fatals;

public void addError(String e)
{

    this.errors.add(e);
}
public void addFatal(String f)
{

    this.fatals.add(f);
}

public void sendLogs() {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();

    for (String e : this.errors)
    {
         log.error("Error Message at "+sdf.format(new Date()) + " for id "+ this.id);
    }
    for (String f : this.fatals)
    {
          log.fatal("Fatal Message at "+sdf.format(new Date()) + " for id "+ this.id);
    }


    }

}
```

now, you only call your sendLogs method after you are sure that ll the messages have been aggregated.
also in your log4j.properties, you can add another smtpappender for this TestLog4j class. you can obviously optimize the code

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.logger.package.TestLog4j = ERROR, sendmail
# turn off additivity
log4j.additivity.package.TestLog4j = false
```

Comment: So, how would I set up the new properties?

Comment: How would I set up log.error and log.fatal? they are in red.

Comment: First, you will create objects of the TestLog4j class, one per application id. Then whenever you catch the exception, you send that message to the TestLog4j object. You will keep on accumulating the error and fatal messages this way for each application. Now lets say application 1 ends. So at the end the TestLog4j object for app 1 will have all the errors and fatals collected in the respective lists. Finally, you just call the sendLogs method for that object

Comment: in your app.properties you will define another smtp appender for the TestLog4j class. remeber, this appender will kick into action whenever the TestLog4j class wants to log something. Since we have customized what we want to log, the appender will send exactly what we want it to. the TestLog4j class is just a template. you can customize as per your needs

Comment: Do you mean log4j.properties? I don't have a app.properties file. If its app.properties can you give me an example?

Comment: Im having a hard time triggering the email.

Comment: Can you show me how to set up the properties.? I would be forever grateful.

Comment: sorry, i meant log4j.properties. yeah sure, i can show the snippet to add. i will edit my answer

Comment: please see the edit. by adding those lines in log4j.properties, i am basically saying that sendmail should be the logger for my TestLog4j class

Comment: I am really busy today. I may get time later to implement this. So, probably Monday I will accept your answer. Unless, I have more questions. Thank you!

Comment: um, so if you have compilation errors, then of course the program wont compile. you will have to fix the compilation errors. log4j is useful for runtime errors and debug messages as you can indicate what you want to log and if something breaks you can easily backtrack and see what went wrong. does that make sense?

Comment: I think I got it working. At this point at least. I appreciate your help. Thanks for following through and being thorough! =)